# Azure worker role for Queue storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-worker-roles

I have created an UI for Creating and manipulating messages and queues in Selected containers with the help of this [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-queues/), I have implemented a Listing of queue wise messages in a listView. up to this all are fine and working as expected. Now i have to implement Listener that listen for changes in selected queues( Once a queue is created, i have to initiate this Listener). Is there any option in azure for achieving this?

Comment: @Cameron : thanks for the quick response, and the provided information. can i use  a worker role for monitoring the changes

Comment: fine, What about worker role? is that possible

Comment: Could you please share me some examples? i have created worker role but have no idea about connecting it to the container

Comment: Not sure quite what's going on but... it appears you're having a conversation with someone in comments. Yet... there are only your comments. If you have edits to make, please make them. But... not sure what you're discussing...